# Force all extends and implements of interface to use bounded generic input

Tags: java, generics

```
public interface AbstractTestStep<I extends StepPojo> {

    public abstract StepResult run(I t);
}

public interface Triggers extends AbstractTestStep{
}

public interface GetInstance extends Triggers{

    StepResult run(GetInstancePojo t);

}
```

I want to force GetInstancePojo to be child class of StepPojo defined from the first top-level interface. How can I achieve that? I have searched for this a lot an not able to find.

Comment: Is the use of `AbstractTestStep` deliberate or did you mean `AbstractStep`? If so make it `public interface <T> Triggers extends AbstractStep<T>`.

Comment: @VivekKrishna that's a typo from him, try to use `interface Triggers<T> extends AbstractStep<T>`

Answer (score 2):

You have to reference that generic parameter throughout the whole hierarchy:

```
public interface AbstractStep<I extends StepPojo>{
    StepResult run(I i);
}

public interface Triggers<I extends StepPojo> extends AbstractStep<I>{}

public interface GetInstance extends Triggers<GetInstancePojo>{}
```

Altough with the current code, you don't even need the `Triggers` interface (provided you don't have additional methods declared in it)

Comment: The problem is to restrict anybody else to define new method with same "run" method name with parameter type other than <I extends StepPojo>. I am still able to define a new method in my GetInstance with parameter other than <I extends StepPojo>. Hope I am not troubling you. Didn't communicate properly I guess.

Comment: @VivekKrishna you can't enforce that, but it isn't even needed. Because when you build an API or something others can use, they need to follow the contract provided by your interface, if they change anything and it doesn't work. Then it's not your fault. In conclusion, don't really bother